# Errno 32 -- Broken pipe for big files

Tags: python, web-services, api, https

I need to send a file to a server which has api chunck by chunck. I'm able to do it, but it only works for files those have size up 1 to Mb. If it's bigger (even 2 Mb), it will return an error of:

```
 File "test1.py", line 39, in <module>
    conn.send(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 794, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 229, in sendall
    v = self.send(data[count:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 198, in send
    v = self._sslobj.write(data)
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Here is my code:

```
import httplib
import json
import sys
import os.path

file_name = "some_file"
total_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
source_file = open(file_name)
path = "/path/param1=value1"
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("www.example.org")
conn.connect()
conn.putrequest("POST", path)
conn.putheader("Content-Type", "some content type")
conn.putheader("Content-Length", str(total_size))
conn.endheaders()
while True:
    chunk = source_file.read(1024)
    if not chunk:
        break
    conn.send(chunk)

response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
print json.loads(data)
```

**UPDATE**:

The more exact error is:

```
Unexpected error: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1246: error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write retry
```

Comment: Hard to tell without more data but I would suspect a size limit on the server side.  If you are using PHP on the server, for example, you would want to check settings like this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: @bgp, I don't know what's used on the server, but there is no size limit. I'm using chuncks, however.

Comment: @bgp, look at my update.

Comment: Gotcha - unfortunately I don't have the info to hand on what that means.  It would appear that something is going out of sync at the actual SSL protocol level - but I really don't know without digging in a lot further, which I can't do right now.  One idea might be to try to send the thing in one big write instead of doing it in chunks - I would definitely try that.

Comment: have you been able to figure out this problem? i'm getting the same one now